# IF statement causing wrong results in function

Tags: r, if-statement

I am trying work on a coursera assignment in R. My code works correctly for assignment 1 where I write a function in R to rank Hospitals; in assignment 2 I have to add few IF or IF ELSE IF statements to the function already written.

Function gives a final dataframe.

1. IF input argument `num==best`, function returns the first row of final data frame
2. IF input argument `num==worst`, function returns the last row of final data frame
3. If input argument `num > max row count` of final data frame, function returns NA
4. If input argument `num< max row count`, function returns that row from data frame

Now, the if statement are working correctly for only scenario 3 and 4. For 1 and 2 scenarios, it is returning NA- which is the return value of scenario 3.

There is something wrong with the way I am writing IF statements ( can be sequence or the condition or something else) because of which I am getting NA return value for scenario 1,2

Code below, TIA

```
outcomeDF<-outcome[,c(2,7,n)]
names(outcomeDF)<-c("Hospital","State","Outcomess")
finalDF<-filter(outcomeDF,outcomeDF$State==sta)
     
DFSlist<-arrange(finalDF,finalDF$State,finalDF$Outcomess,finalDF$Hospital)

if (num > nrow(DFSlist)) print ("NA")
  else if (num < nrow(DFSlist)) c<-(DFSlist[num,])
  else if (num =="best")c<-(DFSlist[1,])
  else (num =="worst")c<-(DFSlist[(nrow(DFSlist)),])
return(c)
```

Comment: `else (num =="worst")` won't work since `else` doesn't take a condition. Here you need again an `if`-statement.

Comment: Thanks. Will take out the condition next to Else

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried wrapping the if statements in braces?

Also, `c()` is the way we make things into vectors, so I'd highly recommend against naming a variable `c`.

```
  # DF manipulation
  outcomeDF <- outcome[, c(2, 7, n)]
  names(outcomeDF) <-c("Hospital", "State", "Outcomess")
  finalDF <- filter(outcomeDF, outcomeDF$State==sta)
  DFSlist <- arrange(finalDF, finalDF$State, finalDF$Outcomess, finalDF$Hospital)

  # results logic
  if (num > nrow(DFSlist)) {
     print ("NA")
  } else if (num < nrow(DFSlist)) {
     res <-(DFSlist[num,])
  } else if (num =="best") {
     res <-(DFSlist[1,])
  } else {
     # (num =="worst") <- this doesn't seem to do anything
     res <-(DFSlist[(nrow(DFSlist)),])
    }

  return(res)
```

Also, by cleaning up your code I found a line of code that was sitting there and probably interfering with your results. That could be the culprit.

Also, `num` isn't defined for this snippet of code, and you have a hanging `}` which you probably know about too.

Comment: Agree that "c" should not be used to name a variable as per naming conventions.

Comment: Wanted to post only a part of complete function, hence the hanging "}". Thx for reminding.

Comment: I still got the "NA" for "best" and "west" scenarios. I am guessing: num takes the class of  argument on Right hand Side of the very first condition (num > nrow(DFSlist), it encounters. Very new R, so can't tell what is the problem.

Comment: Well, another look at this  is suggesting to me that `num` is trying to be an integer, but "best" and "worst" are of class character. Maybe that's where your problem is.

Answer (score 1):

The second part of the Johns Hopkins University Coursera *R Programming* course assignment 3 is a function called `rankhospital()`.

One of the reasons the code in the original post fails is that it makes a direct comparison between `num` and `nrow(DFSlist)`. When `num == "best"` or `num == "worst"`, the first condition in the OP returns TRUE, and returns NA instead of the first row in the `DFSlist` data frame.

The `rankhospital()` function includes two positional arguments, `state`, `outcome`, and one named argument, `num`.

The data for the function comes from the 2012 outcome of care measurements in the Hospital Compare database provided by the U.S. Department of Health and Human Services.

The stub of the required function looks like this.

```
rankhospital <- function(state, outcome, num="best") {
   # answer goes here
}
```

The function needs to do three things, including:

1. Read the hospital outcomes data
2. Validate the input arguments (e.g. check for invalid state, etc.)
3. Process the data and return the n-th ranked hospital in the state specified in the `state` argument for one of three outcomes (heart attack, heart failure, or pneumonia)

The question in the OP asks about how to use the third argument in the function, `num`, to return best, worst, or a numeric rank.

Once the data has been subset to the correct state, and sorted per the instructions, one way to process the `num` argument is as follows.

```
# sort & subset here
 sortedSubset <- # code goes here, includes hospital, state, other variables
                 # sorted in required order (outcome then hospital name)

 # return hospital name, given num argument 
 if (num == "best") {
      return( sortedSubset[1,1]) 
 } else if (num == "worst") {
      return(sortedSubset[nrow(sortedSubset),1])
 } else if (as.numeric(num) > nrow(sortedSubset)) {
      return("NA")
 } else return (sortedSubset[as.numeric(num),1])
```

When working correctly, the function produces the following answers to the test cases that are provided with the assignment instructions.

```
> source("./rprogramming/rankhospital.R")
> rankhospital("TX","heart failure",4)
[1] "DETAR HOSPITAL NAVARRO"
> rankhospital("MD", "heart attack","worst")
[1] "HARFORD MEMORIAL HOSPITAL"
> rankhospital("MN","heart attack",5000)
[1] "NA"
```

**NOTE:**  Posting complete solutions to programming assignments in the JHU Data Science Specialization is a violation of the Coursera Honor Code. Therefore, I explain where the OP code is broken without posting a complete solution for the `rankhospital()` function.

Comment: It's worth mentioning, that `num > nrow(DFSlist)` evaluates to `TRUE` for a non-numeric `num`, i.e. `num == "best`. Your order of conditions smartly avoids that problem.

Comment: @MartinGal - yes, and one of the reasons the code in the OP fails is that the first `if()` compares `num` with the result of `nrow()`, so it will produce the wrong answer when `num` is either "best" or "worst".

Comment: Martin Gal: please explain a little bit more what you mentioned here. Does the num on Left hand side (LHS) take the class of nrow(DFSlist) on Right Hand Side (RHS)? Is it a character vs numeric comparison? eg 11<8.0 for nonnumeric comparison?

Comment: @nancysng00 - answering the question that you asked Martin Gal, when R uses a [relational operator](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/Comparison) to compare objects of different types, it uses the lowest level of precedence of the two types. When comparing a character value to an integer, R casts the integer to character and makes the comparison. For example, `num <- "best"; num < 90000` returns `FALSE` based on a character by character comparison of the ASCII values of each character. Since b is 98 in ASCII and 9 is 57 in ASCII, "best" > "90000".